# Most efficient way for ffmpeg to make thumbnails? [Windows 10]

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails

I normally use ThumbnailMe to make contact sheets of thumbnails.  My default setting is 15 rows x 5 columns, so 75 images, in videos that are anywhere from 45 minutes to around 90 minutes.  ThumbnailMe makes a contact sheet of this size virtually instantaneously.  A recent requirement to make a LOT of contact sheets for a LOT of videos has me looking at a command line option so I can do these in batches.  I've tried a couple different ways to make the thumbnails from the command line:

```
ffmpeg -ss 300 -i myvideo.avi -vf fps=1/300 %d.jpg
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -vf fps=1/60 %d.jpg
```

No matter which of these methods I use it takes roughly a minute to make just 16 screenshots (from there I would use ImageMagick to make the contact sheet).  As I said above, ThumbnailMe can make a 15x5 grid of images at the mere press of a button.  ThumbnailMe is built on an older command line program, Movie Thumbnailer, which I think used an old version of ffmpeg, or at least the codec libavcodec.

If these other programs can create thumbnails so quickly why does it take ffmpeg so long to make them for me?  Even if I output the screenshots in a very small size, say 50x50, it still takes ~2 secs for each image to be created.

Answer (score 3):

The `fps` filter is an inefficient way to go about this. The select filter is a better choice. FFmpeg also has a filter to generate the grid, if you want.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select=not(mod(n\,800)),scale=200:-1,tile=15x5 -vsync 0 in-grid.jpg
```

This selects every 800th frame, scales selected frames proportionally to 200 px width, and then tiles the first 75 selected frames in a 15x5 layout. The tile filter has [options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile) for an outer border and interframe padding, if wanted.

In order to make this as efficient as possible, the select interval (800) should be chosen so that the select filter doesn't output more frames than required for the grid. Also, you can save some time in FFmpeg by omitting the scale and tile and do it elsewhere.

Comment: This does indeed create the grid and is, relatively speaking, faster than the methods I was using.  However, I next tried this on a high def video (bit rate 5000 Kbps, 1280x720 with AVC format) and it took over 60 seconds to generate the grid.

Answer (score 1):

I use **mt** https://github.com/mutschler/mt/releases for my contact sheets which is pretty fast and should offer everything you where asking for.

I've just did a quick test and it took me about 27 Seconds to generate a 15x5 grid in default mode. In fast mode it only took about 4 Seconds. (tested on a 6300Kbp/s, 1280x720, h264 AVC file)

The main difference between fast and the default mode is that it is a little bit more inaccurate when fast forwarding to the next capture position.